# how to insert data in two different table at same,but in Admission_Education Table i have to entered more 4 values on single id

Tags: sql-server

table first

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Admission_Education](
    [Edu_id] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [Education] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [S_Bord] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [S_Strem] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [S_year] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [S_marks] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [Admi_id] [nvarchar](200) NULL,PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (  [Edu_id] ASC)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

table second

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].Admission_Table](
    [Admi_id] [nvarchar](200) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [Dob] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [Gender] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [email] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [Stu_mobile] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [Stu_phone] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [Name_inst] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Address] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [Name_father] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [F_mobile] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [Inter_sub] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [C_id] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [Photo] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Status] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Admission_Table] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
```

Comment: We don't have near enough information about what you want, for us to give you an answer

Comment: Going to flag as improper details

Comment: Please edit your question to include sample data, desired output, and your current attempt.

Answer (score 0):

You can [insert data into two tables using SQL Output clause with Insert](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/insert-into-two-tables-using-t-sql-output-clause.aspx) statement

Please check the referred tutorial for how to use it. I'm not actually sure it will fit your requirement. But Output clause enables, inserted or deleted data into an other table and it can be used with auditing and logging purposes.

You can also check [MSDN for Output clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx)